# Converting a "string" to "float"?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a .txt file of lines of the form:

```
filename.txt  date    magnitude
V098550.txt   362.0   3.34717962317
```

but I am getting the error "could not convert string to float: V113573.txt". Does anyone know if this is a syntax error with numpy, or how I can resolve my issue?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x, y = np.loadtxt ("condensed.txt", usecols=(0, 1), delimiter=",", 
unpack=True)
for ii in range (len(x)):
    x[ii].replace('.txt', '.lc\n')
    jd, npmag = np.loadtxt 
    ("/net/jovan/export/jovan/oelkerrj/Vela/rotation/Vela/"+x[ii], usecols=
(0, 1), unpack=True)
    plt.scatter (jd, npmag)
    plt.xlabel ('Time')
    plt.ylabel ('Mag')
    plt.ylim ([max (npmag), min (npmag)])
    plt.show() # aftertest comment this out
    fileName = x[ii][:-3] + ".png"
    plt.savefig(fileName)
print "done"
```

Comment: You want to use columns `(1, 2)`. Column `0`  contains filenames like `'V098550.txt'` which, as the error message indicates, can't be converted to a float.

Comment: Note: if your code breaks at the `np.loadtxt` call, there is no point in including the code after that. When you get past `np.loadtxt`, however, you will have to work on the rest of the code, too.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Could you point out some of the errors and what I can do to fix them?

Comment: The replace method of str doesn't change the string in place, because strings are immutable in Python. Instead, a new string is returned, and you should use it instead of the original.

Comment: As to your current problem, you need to provide the dtype argument to [loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to tell it that the first column is of type str.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find everything that's wrong in the code, so one needs to start at the beginning. First it seems the datafile has whitespaces as delimiter, so you need to remove `delimiter=","` as there is no comma in the file.

Next, you cannot convert the string `V098550.txt` from the file to a float. Instead it needs to stay a string. You can use a converter in the `loadtxt` and set the `dtype` for that column to string.

So you may start with the following, and see how far you can get with it. If more errors come up, one would also need to know the content of `V098550.txt`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

conv = {0: lambda x: x.replace('.txt', ".lc")}
x, y = np.loadtxt("condensed.txt", usecols=(0, 1),  delimiter="   ", 
                  unpack=True, converters=conv, dtype=(str, str), skiprows=1 )

for ii in range (len(x)):
    jd, npmag = np.loadtxt("/net/jovan/export/jovan/oelkerrj/Vela/rotation/Vela/"+x[ii], usecols=(0, 1), unpack=True)
    plt.scatter (jd, npmag)
    plt.xlabel ('Time')
    plt.ylabel ('Mag')
    plt.ylim ([max (npmag), min (npmag)])
    plt.show() # aftertest comment this out
    fileName = x[ii][:-3] + ".png"
    plt.savefig(fileName)

print "done"
```